# How can I remove multiple 'BAD' values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose $arr is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 43
[1] => 120
[2] => 5
[3] => 5465
[4] => 397
)
```

and I want any values between 111-5000 to be removed.  If done correctly, my array would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => 43
[1] => 5
[2] => 5465

)
```

Hopefully the keys update on their own.  Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/function.array-filter) with a custom callback that removes unwanted values:

```
$array = array(43,120,5,5465,397);
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($val){
    return ($val < 111 || $val > 5000);
});
print_r($filtered); // Array ( [0] => 43 [2] => 5 [3] => 5465 )
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ujqo87)

You can also do

```
$array = array(43,120,5,5465,397);
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($val){
    return !($val > 111 && $val < 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using the following logic too.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value >= 111 && $value <= 5000) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

But what John mentioned in the above post is the optimal solution. It's quicker than this logic.

Thanks!